# Getting element instance from child component in the parent and code is runnign twice

Tags: vuejs3

Trying to get data from a child component inside the parent component but its not working proper, the event is fired but runs twice, first time with no data(mouseEvents info)

**EDIT**

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div> 
       <button @clickEventChild="formSubmit"/>
    </div> 
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       methods: {
           const formSubmit = e => {
               console.log(e) //first time it will output mouseEvents...
               if (e.submitter) { // prevents running twice
                   e.submitter.classList.add('active'); 
                   ...
               }
           }
       }
   }
</script>
```

**child.vue**

```
<template>
    <div> 
        <button class="btn" @click="handleClick"> 
          save
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        emits:['clickEventChild'],
        methods: {
            handleClick: function(e) {
                this.$emit("clickEventChild", e);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that _should_ work, other than the format of the `formSubmit` method which should be `formSubmit(e){`  the code seems fine. If you're having issues with it generating extra events, it might from some other code that's not included here.

Comment: okay this works, it is now running just once.